# How to remove public from URL in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

The code of my .htaccess file is shown below.It is placed in my laravel project root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>

</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Using this when I run the url "http://localhost/laravelapi/" I am getting folder structure. But when I run  "http://localhost/laravelapi/public" I am getting the result page. What will be the problem? Please help me to find a solution..

Comment: You can either add a vhost or do this using htacess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already copied the .htaccess file from /public directory to my Laravel root folder.Also I renamed the server.php in the my Laravel root folder to index.php and its worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Copy .htaccess file from public folder to your Laravel root folder and copy the server.php in the same folder as index.php . That'll do

Answer (score 0):

add public folder to your root folder of project and run "php artisan serve" command to run you project